# Meta-analytic test of variances (but not variances of differences)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, meta-analysis

There is a substantial literature on what I don't want to do, which is analyzing the variance across studies of a treatment versus control group. What I want to do should be simpler:

I have 11 samples of Type 1 people and 11 samples of Type 2 people. My dependent variable, Y, has more variance for Type 1 people, reflected both in the variation of the sample means of Type 1 people and in the variation within samples.

I conducted a Fisher’s F ratio test of the variance in sample means between Type 1 and Type 2 samples, and it was statistically significant. However, I’m unsure if this is a good approach. (People worry about normality. The variable Y is not normally distributed, although of course sample means will be normally distributed for a given sample size. Samples vary widely in size.)

Nor do I know how to compare the within-samples variance. Just a quick and dirty and probably completely incorrect t-test of standard deviations between the two types of samples is highly significant.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do the 11 samples of each Type come from the same set of 11 'studies'? In other words, is the first variance for Type 1 paired with the first variance for Type 2?